# Accessing EventGridEvent.EventType in Azure function binding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure function triggered by an `EventGridEvent`. I'm trying to store all events in Azure tables and give each table the name of the event.

This is how I would solve it without binding:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task MyFunction([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent)
{
    var table = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage")).CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(eventGridEvent.EventType);
    await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    // etc...
}
```

But I would like to accomplish it with bindings.

This is what I tried:

```
 [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
 public static async Task MyFunction(
     [EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
     [Table("{EventType}")] CloudTable table)
    {
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MyFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve binding parameter 'EventType'. Binding expressions must map to either a value provided by the trigger **or a property of the value the trigger is bound to**, or must be a system binding expression (e.g. sys.randguid, sys.utcnow, etc.).

Surely `EventType` is a property of `EventGridEvent` which the trigger is bound to?

How should I access `EventGridEvent.EventType` in the binding?

Comment: Can you try to do something similar like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248690/azure-functions-dynamic-input-output-binding-based-on-service-bus-trigger-mess

Comment: I tried, but I get the same error...

Comment: they go in local.settings.json for local debug and application configuration in azure for production

Comment: Did you try `{eventType}` (small 'e')? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=csharp%2Cbash#event-schema

Comment: Yes, I've tried `{eventType}` as well, but still get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, for Event Grid trigger/binding, that kind of property binding expression (e.g. `{EventType}`) is not supported. That's why you don't see that in [Event Grid trigger doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger#usage) as opposed to places where such binding is supported (e.g. [Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#message-metadata))